How to use Custom CI/CD action for building dotNet in Mumbai region?
I need to build a dotNet framework application that can only be build with Windows environment I'm trying to setup a CICD pipeline for it but on AWS CodeBuild Mumbai region there is only Linux machines available due to compliance I cannot move my code out for India.
Is there any custom actions that I can perform to fix my issue here?

Yes it is possible to create a custom action build that will happen on managed Windows EC2 machie pls refer to the following blog..
https://blog.shellkode.com/build-compliant-windows-applications-using-aws-codebuild-in-indian-regions-d972f5c997db
